# Could an object reinitialize itself before a method is executed?

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, pageobjects

Can I have an object reinitialize itself before a method is executed?  I'm using Ruby and selenium to test a web app and I am trying to improve my page objects.  for example

```
class Foo

  def initialize
    #stuff happens here 
  end

  def NewMethod
    self.initialize
    #What happens here is what I really want to happen 
  end 

end
```

Is this a good or bad idea?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please improve your question by providing more details, it's not clear what is being asked here.

Comment: I'm trying to plan out how to make my page objects responsible for for what is on the page rather than checking for things in the test case.  What I am trying to work out here is a strategy for making a page object of a navigation bar.  I think I am now leaning in the direction of having all page objects that would have a nav bar on them inherit from a nav bar class.

Answer (score 0):

it's always possible to change the data contained in your object. you could ie put all the init-logic into an additional method and then call that from your custom methods.

in general, what you are trying to do does not sound like a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

A remark in advance: methods are written in lower case. Please replace `NewMethod` with `newmethod`.

If you try `Foo.newmethod` you get an error.

What do you want to do? Do you want to define different possibilities to create an object?

What you could do:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
  end

  def self.newmethod
    me = self.new
    #Some actions ...
    me #Return the (modified?) object
  end 

end 

p Foo.newmethod #->#<Foo:0xb77d58>
```

`Time` is using something like this. There is `Time.new`, `Time.gm`, `Time.local`...